# SQL multiple select with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a data table "BondPrices" with the following values:

```
date     | type | price  
1/5/2019   bid    104.50  
1/5/2019   bid    104.75
1/6/2019   bid    104.40  
1/6/2019   bid    104.45   
1/5/2019   offer  106.75   
1/5/2019   offer  107.75
1/6/2019   offer  106.23
1/6/2019   offer  106.47
```

I want to write a query that gives the highest price for bids and the lowest price for offers on a given date, like the following output:

```
date     | Highest Bid | Lowest Offer
1/5/2019   104.75        106.75
1/6/2019   104.45        106.23
```

I can achieve either highest bid or lowest offer by doing

```
SELECT "date", max("price") AS "Highest Bid"
FROM "BondPrices" 
WHERE "type"='bid' 
GROUP BY "date"
```

or

```
SELECT "date", min("price") AS "Lowest Offer"
FROM "BondPrices" 
WHERE "type"='offer' 
GROUP BY "date"
```

but when I try to combine them (such as with JOIN) I get a syntax error.

**How do I write a select statement with multiple conditions resulting in multiple columns?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to skin the cat here, this will get you there:

```
SELECT
    CAST(date AS DATE) Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'bid' THEN price ELSE NULL END) HighestBid,
    MIN(CASE WHEN type = 'offer' THEN price ELSE NULL END) LowestOffer
FROM 
    BondPrices
GROUP BY 
    CAST(date AS DATE)
```